# Spectral theorem for $n$-tuples of selfadjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory

I need a 'good' reference to the following version of the Spectral Theorem:

Given $n$ commuting selfadjoint operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, there exist a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ and auxiliary Hilbert spaces $h(x)$ such that the construction is unitarily equivalent to $\int\oplus h(x)\,d\mu(x)$ with selfadjoint operators of multiplication by $x_k$, $k=1, \dots, n$.

It is important that the construction be based on a measure in $\mathbb R^n$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the operators bounded?

Comment: Let them be bounded, if this helps

Comment: Is it a direct integral there?

Comment: Yes, as usual for the spectral theorem.

Comment: A direct sum is enough

Comment: If your operators have a cyclic vector, then you have one Hilbert space

Comment: Yes, one can take just the usual $L^2(\mu)$. Even this partial case is of interest.

Comment: But you can always decompose $H$ into direct sum of common invariant subspaces $H_i$ such that every $H_i$ has a cyclic vector.

Comment: I don't care about multiplicities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can find such theorem precisely in that form. Instead you can find the following

**Spectral theorem.** For $n$ bounded commuting self-adjoint operators $X_1,\dots,X_n$ on a Hilbert space $H$ there exists a unique projection valued measure $E$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $X_k=\int x_k dE(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for all $k=1,\dots,n.$

Then using the following two (easy) Lemmas you get your version of the spectral theorem.

**Lemma 1.** $H$ can be decomposed into direct sum of common invariant subspaces $H_i,\ i\in I$ such that every $H_i$ is cyclic for the set $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ with a cyclic vector $\xi_i.$

**Lemma 2.** Let $H_i,\xi_i$ be as in Lemma 1. Define $\mu_i(\cdot)=\langle E(\cdot)\xi_i,\xi_i\rangle.$ Then every $H_i$ is isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb R^n,\mu_i)$ and $X_k$ are unitarily equivalent (under that isomorphism) to multiplication operators by $x_k.$

That spectral theorem you can find in the books:

*Birman, Solomyak* "Spectral theory of self-adjoint operators in Hilbert space,"

*Yu. Samoilenko* "Spectral theory of families of self-adjoint operators",

*Yu. Berezanskii* "Self-adjoint operators in spaces of functions of infinitely many variables" (in russian)

Comment: As far as I remember, I did not find this in 'Birman, Solomyak', but unfortunately I cannot check this now again. Are you sure?

Comment: Check Birman, Solomyak Chapter 6, Section 5, Theorem 1.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much (I have found it in the net).